# Is it ever beneficial to generate layout of an html page in excel as oppose to creating in css?

Tags: javascript, html, css, d3.js

I am creating a dashboard for reporting purposes using html, d3.js for visualization, and css for layout. This dashboard will be used internally by about 25 people and will hold about 7-8 components. My colleagues are making an argument that we should design layout in excel, generate html from it and just plugin d3 components. They are agreeing that css is better for layouts but since management may ask us to move/resize components several times its better to create layout in excel as it will save time to cater their future requests.

My argument against that is first of all it won't take that much extra time to move/resize components if css is done properly. Second, the code excel generates which is just ugly and humongous, contains tons of tables even when there is no tabular data and is twice or thrice longer than what i would write in css. I understand the need to be agile and save time but isn't this a bit too much?

Comment: Did your colleagues make this argument on April Fools' Day?

Comment: @JonathanS. i am afraid not lol!

Comment: Doesn't Excel generate LARGE amounts of HTML and CSS to accomplish even the smallest of pages?

Comment: For this question, a more appropriate forum is at http://thedailywtf.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds to me like your colleagues are more comfortable with Excel than HTML/CSS.

If you are truly just creating 7 or 8 containers, the HTML should be simple and the CSS would only need a reference to each container to set particular layout criteria.

Worst case scenario is that you would need to tweak sizes of the containers and possibly do a little bit of reshuffling of them if you couldn't get the desired layout by floating, etc.. (though I guess you could just hack it and use absolute positioning for everything).

If nothing else think of the poor person that has to maintain it. Of course you can always go down the route of discussing the use of tables for layout purposes as well.